# Sonarqube vs jacoco code coverage difference

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I am getting, the difference in sonarqube and jacoco test coverage for my gradle project, the difference is as per below :

Sonarqube - 55 %

Jacoco - 72 %

Whenever i am executing below command :

gradle clean build all --parallel sonarqube

Comment: Add some  more details

Comment: I've found with some test coverage code it's very specific to using generics, or lambda functions, such that it may ignore those lines.